# How to remove duplicate values in a list in powerbi report dataset?

Tags: list, powerbi, powerquery

Hope you are staying safe. I have a column in my powerbi report dataset which holds list values in a column.

```
Id       Name
1        kevin,yona,rachel,kevin
2        bruce,miller,kim
3        adam,rita,adam,adam
```

As you can see there are duplicate values in the list on Name column. I wanted to write a query which will remove those duplicates and and keep one occurences. the result set i want is like this

```
Id       Name
1        yona,rachel,kevin
2        bruce,miller,kim
3        adam,rita
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split, remove duplicates and group by again.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Hck7CoBADIThu6SeRj1O2CKuAcO+IKjg7V3TDD/zMdNCoKKPdbyjC1zyqRXxUALTOn33Oyua1aqOYi1gmyCHNLhdgqh/KKUP", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column2"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Column1"}, {{"Rows", each _, type table [Column1=number, Column2=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [Rows][Column2]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Rows"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```